# Django haystack related name search

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

so i have the following models:

```
class Article(models.Model, PublicationMixin):
    publication = models.ForeignKey('Publication', related_name="articles")
    ...

class Publication(models.Model, PublicationMixin):
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ....
```

in my `search_indexes.py` i have:

```
class PublicationIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    id = indexes.CharField(model_attr='id', null=True)
```

I am trying to apply a filter that goes into my `searchform` and returns only the publications that have articles.

How can i achieve that using haystack and related names?? I am using elastic search as the backend.

Comment: have you tried to reference the articles field in the index like this: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#advanced-data-preparation

and then use the SearchQuerySetApi to retrieve the values you want: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html

Comment: thanks @danielfranca you pointed me in the right direction. if you wanna write a proper answer ill mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to reference the articles field in the index like this: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#advanced-data-preparation and then use the SearchQuerySetApi to retrieve the values you want: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html

:)